Public function vba
I am trying to set a public function that searches for an identifier in some worksheet column A and returns its row number so i put this function like this:
Public Function Row_Index_CellID(ws As Worksheet, CellID As String) As Long
    Dim FindRowNumber As Long
    Dim FindRow As Range
    ws.Activate
    With ws
            Set FindRow = ws.Range("A1").Find(CellID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    FindRowNumber = ws.Cells.Find(What:=CellID, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row - 2
    End With
    Row_Index_CellID(ws, CellID) = FindRowNumber
End Function

But I had the error "Function Call on left hand side of assignment must return a variant or object" at the line:
Row_Index_CellID(ws, CellID) = FindRowNumber

so when i declared the function as variant:
Public Function Row_Index_CellID(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef CellID As String) As Variant

I had the error "Out of stack space" at the same line as before! can you help me please?

The line: Row_Index_CellID = FindRowNumber without arguments. In addition, you do not need to activate the ws sheet. Instead, add a dot before Cells: After:=.Cells(1, 1)

Please explain what the function is supposed to return best by sharing a practical example, e.g., if CellID is located in A5, what should be the result and why? What is the first (top) cell to search in (since it isn't cell A1)?

To set the value returned by the function use the function name only:
Row_Index_CellID = FindRowNumber

In the first case it's the syntax error, in the second case you call the function recurrently until the stack exhausts. The second case is syntaxial correct because the returning Varian can be a reference to the object (e. g. Range) which can accept a value.
UPD
Row_Index_CellID returns 0 if ws.Cells.Find(...).Row returns 2.
Optimized code:
Public Function Row_Index_CellID(ws As Worksheet, CellID As String) As Variant
  Dim FindRow As Range
  Set FindRow = ws.UsedRange.Find(What:=CellID, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  Row_Index_CellID = IIf(FindRow Is Nothing, CVErr(xlErrNA), FindRow.Row)
End Function

If the search area is the column "A" only:
Public Function Row_Index_CellID(ws As Worksheet, CellID As String) As Variant
  Dim FindRow As Range
  With ws.Columns(1)
    Set FindRow = .Find(What:=CellID, After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  End With
  Row_Index_CellID = IIf(FindRow Is Nothing, CVErr(xlErrNA), FindRow.Row - 2)
End Function


oh great thanks! the error is gone but the problem now is it returns 0 as value after i inserted debug.print Row_Index_CellID(Statistics_CellIDs, Local_CellID) line, 0 is not even correct as row number!

Let me to check your code again to help you with the new problem.

so if the search returns 2 that means it returned the first non empty cell of the column which means it didn't even search for my value!!!

many thanks brother that worked perfectly! you're the chosen one :D
